# Ubuntu 12.04 partioning an external drive without lossing data

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 with an external 1.5T disk (just for data). It is **/dev/sdc1** seen below:

```
$ df -T
Filesystem        Type      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1         ext4     1451144932  27722584 1350794536   3% /
udev              devtmpfs    6199460         4    6199456   1% /dev
tmpfs             tmpfs       2482692       988    2481704   1% /run
none              tmpfs          5120         0       5120   0% /run/lock
none              tmpfs       6206724       284    6206440   1% /run/shm
/dev/sdc1         fuseblk  1465135100 172507664 1292627436  12% /media/Elements
```

The thing is I would like to implement this [rsync-based backup strategy](http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/) and I want to use my **/dev/sdc1** external drive for that. Since the guide mentioned above recommends placing the backup directory in a separate partition I want to repartition the /dev/sdc1 external hard disk **but retain existing data** in a separate partition. E.g. split /dev/sdc1 into two partitions: (i) one to be used exclusively for the rsync-based backup and (ii) the other for the existing miscellaneous data. How should I go about partitioning with minimal risk to my existing data and what kind of filesystem do you recommend? I would prefer a console-based guide but unfortunately all the material I found on the web is oriented towards partitioning the main (bootable) disk and not an external **fuseblk** filesystem used only for passive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resizing partitions is a time-consuming operation, and is subject to occasional cases of losing all the data, so I strongly recommend NOT doing that.
Having been in this situation several times, I have a finely tuned procedure I use.

1. copy/rsync all the data from `/media/Elements` to a staging directory (probably in your home directory somewhere)
2. repartition /dev/sdc as you see fit, into whatever shapes you want
3. copy/rsync all the data back to the new partition `/media/Elements` (or whatever you name it)
4. delete the local staged copy

This is my recommendation AND the procedures I use regularly when needing to "change the size" of partitions and such.

Comment: The most important aspect of your suggestion is to make a backup.